# show search results and highlight them in gridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have populated a grid view with data and it works properly and I have also written this code to search and highlight the results on button click:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
        }
    }
```

now my question is how can I change this code to pnly show the result as members of grid view along with highlighting them

Comment: you need to highlight the result and that is not happening is this right?

Comment: it highlights them but the results are shown in between all other data and it's hard to see them. I want to see only the highlighted results in grid view.

Comment: do you have the last row(the one with no data) displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding the rows that don't match with search criteria:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["CardSerial"].Value.ToString().Equals(textBox2.Text))
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```